# Not able to send the dropdown selected option from index.php to controller and then to search.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

This is my `index.php`

```
<form class="form-horizontal well bar" action="<?php echo base_url();?>search" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="col-md-2">       
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select class = "course" name = "course_offrd-name[]" onchange="" id = "course_offrd_name" class = "form-control">
                    <option value="">Select</option>    

                    <?php 
                    foreach($coursedata as $val)
                    {
                    ?>              

                    <option value="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name;?>">

                    <?php
                    echo  $val->course_offrd_name; 
                    ?>

                    </option> 
                    <?php
                    } 
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

This is Javascript code in `index.php` page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select.course").change(function () {
        var selectedCourse = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        alert("You have selected the course - " + selectedCourse);
    });
});
</script>
```

this is ajax code in `index.php` page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".course").on('change', function() 
    {
        var level = $(this).val();
        if(level)
        {
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: base_url+"home/search",
                data: {course_offrd_name: selectedCourse},
                success : function(htmlresponse) 
                {
                    $('#opt_lesson_list').html(htmlresponse);
                    console.log(htmlresponse);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my controller

```
public function search()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('course_offrd_name');

    $data['result']   = $this->front->get_data_wheree($id);
    $this->load->view('home/search', $data);
}
```

This is my model

```
function get_data_wheree($table)
{
    $this->db->select('course_offrd_name, collg_id');
    $this->db->group_by('course_offrd_name');
    return $this->db->get('tbl_course_offered')->result();
}
```

This is `search.php` file ie here i want to display the selected dropdown option

```
<?php 
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo $row['course_offrd_name'];
}
?>
```

Satabase table name is `tbl_course_offered` it has `collg_id and course_offrd_name` column.

My dropdowndown option is comming from `course_offrd_name`

**Problems:** I have page `index.php` and I have two dropdown option say two courses science and Maths.
If i selected science from downdown and submit the button it redirect the page to search.php and should display science on search.php page.

I have used ajax code for that trying to send the data to controller and then to search.php but not getting the result.

My dropdown option is actually not able to send inside the controller search function and then to search.php.

What is the issue in the code?

my dropdown option send is failed from ajax to controller only and then to controller to `search.php`.

I m using Codeigniter3
why i m not able to send the dropdown option from `index.php` to controller and then to `search.php` page?
why i m not getting the post data in controller?

If any file is required will help you.

Comment: Since you have `[]` in the end of the name `course_offrd-name[]` for your select box, it will be turned into an array.  So in your controller, `$id` will be an array.  Try removing `[]` and check if it works better. If it doesn't, you need to do some debugging. In your browsers development tools, check if the ajax request is sent properly with the correct values. Also check the response.

Comment: Btw, you're passing `$table` to your `get_data_wheree($table)`, but you never actually _use_ that variable anywhere.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  i tried removing [] but still not getting the proper output

Comment: output: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [course_offrd_name] => Bachelor in Mechanical [collg_id] => 46 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [course_offrd_name] => bsc [collg_id] => 44 ) )

Comment: Read my second comment.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have also done  get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered'); but still not getting proper output

Comment: Sure, but you're not _using_ that value at all in that function, so it won't matter what you pass in.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how to use that value in search function....i do not know how to do that

Comment: Then I would recommend that you read the documentation. I'm not 100% sure what your database actually looks like (and I haven't used CodeIgniter for many years) so I can't give you a proper example.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson    here i m using that value  $id = $this->input->post('course_offrd_name');

Comment: Yes, and then you pass `$id` to the method `get_data_wheree()` where you're not using it at all.